# How do I reference a sub-column from a pivoted table inside a method such as sort_values?

Tags: python, pandas

[This table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TcX6.jpg) has 2 level of columns after pivotting col2. I want to sort the table with df['col3']['A'], but in `.sort_values()` you can only use a string or a list of strings to reference column(s).

I know for this specific problem, I can just sort the table before pivotting. But this problem applies to all other methods e.g. `df.style.set_properties( subset=...)` on any dataframes with multi-level/hierarchical columns.

---

EDIT:

Table here:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      |        col3         |        col4         |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| col2 |    A     |    B     |    A     |    B     |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| col1 |          |          |          |          |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1    | 0.242926 | 0.181175 | 0.189465 | 0.338340 |
| 2    | 0.240864 | 0.494611 | 0.211883 | 0.614739 |
| 3    | 0.052051 | 0.757591 | 0.361446 | 0.389341 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe(or an example) and your expected output

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: [Sort Pandas Pivot Table by the margin ('All') values column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652270/sort-pandas-pivot-table-by-the-margin-all-values-column?rq=1)

Basically just put the column and sub column(s) in a tuple. i.e. for my case, it is just `.sort_values(('col3','A'))`.

Comment: This doesn't work for methods that ask for `subset`.

Comment: Good answer for methods requiring `subset`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41738653/12132601